# batch convert images to webp using cwebp

Tags: regex, bash-scripting

I am trying to convert images in a folder to webp using cwebp

I picked up @InfinitePrime solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565191/batch-process-png-to-webp)

```
for file in *;
do cwebp -q 50 -m 6 -z 9 $file -o $file.webp;
done;
```

While it works; the output is image.jpg.webp. Is there any way to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the webp on the end is q&d and works.  If you actually want to replace jpg with webp then you'll need to come up with the new name manually or rename afterwards.  Also you could do this in parallel with a large list of images to make it go faster.  You could try something like this:

```
for file in *;
do cwebp -q 50 -m 6 -z 9 $file -o $(echo "$file" | sed 's/jpg/webp/');
done;
```

For parallel try this:

```
find . -iname '*.jp*g' | parallel 'cwebp -q 50 -m 6 -z 9 {} -o {}.webp'
```

But you'll have to rename them afterwards if you use ^ method.

Comment: Is it also possible to literate through png, jpg, jpeg and other formats at the same time?

Comment: Yes those should work too. The only exception is animated GIFs which you'll need to use gif2webp